# FluentValidation checking for duplicate entity in a sub-collection

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a `MainEntity` class and it has a collection of `SubEntity`. The following is the current validation:

```
public class MainEntityValidator : AbstractValidator<MainEntity>
{
    public MainEntityValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.SubEntities).SetCollectionValidator(new SubEntityValidator());
    }

    public class SubEntityValidator : AbstractValidator<SubEntity>
    {
        public SubEntityValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Field1).NotNull();
            RuleFor(x => x.Field2).NotNull();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I add a validation rule so that only unique `SubEntity` objects (based on `Field1` and `Field2`) must be in the collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to apply validation rule to collection property but still need access to main model and(or) whole collection, not only item being validated, then `RuleForEach` method is your choice:

```
var comparer = new SubEntityComparer();

RuleForEach(x => x.SubEntities)
    .Must((model, submodel) => model.SubEntities.Count(xsub => comparer.Equals(xsub, submodel)) == 1) // one match that ReferenceEquals hit
    .WithMessage("The item with values {0}, {1} has duplicates in collection of {2} items",
        (model, submodel) => submodel.Field1,
        (model, submodel) => submodel.Field2,
        (model, submodel) => model.SubEntities.Count); // in validation message generation you can access to current item as well as to main model
```

If you need only one error message for validation rule you described — you can apply simple predicate rule to collection property `SubEntites`:

```
RuleFor(x => x.SubEntities)
    .Must(coll => coll.Distinct(new SubEntityComparer()).Count() == coll.Count)
    .WithMessage("One or more items in collection of {0} items are duplicates",
        (model, coll) => coll.Count); // has access to collection and to main model
```

In both cases I used the same equality comparer, but you can override `Equals` method as well, and use overloads of `IEnumerable` extension methods with overload, that exclude `EqualityComparer` parameter.

Code of EqualityComparer listed below:

```
public class SubEntityComparer : IEqualityComparer<SubEntity>
{
    public bool Equals(SubEntity x, SubEntity y)
    {
        if (x == null ^ y == null)
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        // your equality comparison logic goes here:
        return x.Field1 == y.Field1 &&
               x.Field2 == y.Field2;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SubEntity obj)
    {
        return obj.Field1.GetHashCode() + 37 * obj.Field2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In both ways to implement validation for collection you still can use `SetCollectionValidator(new SubEntityValidator())` to validate each item with simple rules independently.

Comment: Don't you need to dispose SubEntityComparer?

Comment: IEqualityComparer implementation stateless (no fields), moreover, it participate in closure - validation method would be executed after rules definition code has finished.

Comment: Why did you choose to implement the comparer, rather than simply doing this: `.Must((model, submodel) => model.SubEntities.Count(xsub => xsub.Field1 == submodel.Field1 && xsub.Field2 == submodel.Field2)) == 1)` ?

Comment: The "update" is now very old - `SetCollectionValidator` was deprecated and removed long ago if anyone is looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the answer to your question is to compare every item in your collection to every other item and fail validation when to objects are "equal".  Though I would not recommend doing that if your collection could contain more than a trivial number of items.  A better approach would be to implement Equals() and GetHashCode() so that the collection types in the base class library will handle your SubEntity objects predictably.  I would post an example but I don't know what your objects look like as you have not posted them.  At any rate, if you implement those methods in a meaningful way you can define your collection as a type that already has the appropriate unique constraints (HashSet of T for instance).