# .NET FluentValidation: Validate against a collection of the same type: overlapping dates

Tags: .net, fluentvalidation

Is it possible to validate against a collection with the FluentValidation library. E.g., checking if a new object's start/end dates overlap with ones inside a collection of the same type? If not, does anyone have any recommendations on to perform this type of validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate a collection of items, that shouldn't overlap each other — you can use approach I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30336047/571203). Just change `IEqualityComparer` implementation to return `true` when date intervals overlap each other.

**UPDATE**

If your collection not related with view model and placed in DB, for example, you can use simple predicate that return result of your business logic (constructor injection of known interface used in example):

```
public class ViewModelValidator
{
    public ViewModelValidator(IIntervalService intervalService)
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.NewInterval)
            .Must(interval => !intervalService.IsOverlapExistingIntervals(interval.StartDate, interval.EndDate));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this method have to use a subordinate collection? I am trying to validate against an existing collection not tied to the object I am validating. E.g., before I add the object to the collection, I want to ensure that it doesn't overlap with existing dates. Perhaps I could overload the Validate function with the collection I am trying to validate against and then add a rule that checks if it overlaps???

Comment: Thanks for your help good sir. I was able to make this work in my scenario.